# Format cells based on pandas dataframe range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have two pandas dataframe as below. I want to change font color of all the rows in the 2nd dataframe(df2) to red (The code should take the dataframe range not A7:A8, because the range might go up or down based on the dataframe)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': [10, 20, 30],
                   'Data2': [11, 21, 31],
                   'Date': [pd.to_datetime('today'), 
                            "", 
                            pd.to_datetime('today')]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': ["A", "B"]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_filter.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', )
workbook  = writer.book

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, startrow=df1.shape[0]+2 , startcol=0)
writer.save()
```

I am expecting the output as shown in the screenshot below
[image]

The below code doesnot seem to work:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': [10, 20, 30],
                   'Data2': [11, 21, 31],
                   'Date': [pd.to_datetime('today'), 
                            "", 
                            pd.to_datetime('today')]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': ["A", "B"]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_filter.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', )
workbook  = writer.book

df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, startrow=df1.shape[0]+2 , startcol=0)

def to_red():
    return 'color: red'

df2.style.applymap(to_red)

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a parameter in your defined function and you must re-assign the styling object back to df2.

Try:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': [10, 20, 30],
                   'Data2': [11, 21, 31],
                   'Date': [pd.to_datetime('today'), 
                            "", 
                            pd.to_datetime('today')]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data1': ["A", "B"]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_filter.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter', )
workbook  = writer.book


#Note change in following line
def to_red(val):
    return 'color: red'

df2 = df2.style.applymap(to_red)
#Note move write lines after saving stying to df2 variable again.
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, startrow=df1.shape[0]+2 , startcol=0)

writer.save()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I am getting "AttributeError: 'Styler' object has no attribute 'to_excel'" error when I tried the your code

Comment: Hrm. code runs fine with pandas 0.24.2... try and update pandas.

Comment: I updated my pandas version and it works fine. Thanks!